# Connecting front-end and back-end with react and mongo DB - 404 error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to connect an app hosted in my localhost:3000 port. The back-end is on the localhost:8080 port (not a remote API but on my own PC. I downloaded a pre-created back-end api and linked the front-end to the back-end with MongoDB using an .env file.

The weird thing is that on MongoDB the connection looks ok, following the tutorial I am using. The backend and the front-end also look alrigh, however, I am unable to login with the form in the screenshot.The error I get when trying to login or create a new user is "xhr.js:178 POST http://localhost:3000/login 404 (Not Found)"

It was a bit hard to put the whole code here, so I am linking you to the front-end repo: https://github.com/manuelalonge/complex-app and the back-end repo: https://github.com/manuelalonge/back-end-api

I can understand the issue is most likely on the back-end but I could not understand where exactly. I tried to get back to the previous lessons in the tutorial but it still doesn't get solved.

Probably it is easier to solve this issue with a screenshare session, so if anybody would contact me I'll be grateful.

Screenshot -->  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVJzn.png

Comment: You're posting to `/login`,

Comment: Hi, yes I can see that but I'm not sure which part of the code I'm supposed to change in order to fix this. Is it maybe Main.js?

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot points to what's wrong. You're posting to `localhost:3000`, as you know this is the frontend webpack server.

You'll want to create an axios config file and set a base url to hit the correct endpoint.

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'localhost:8080'
});

export default axiosInstance;
```

Also, please add some sort of file structure.

Comment: Ok, now I have added the instance you've suggested me to add. I'm still not sure where to import it though. I have tried with importing it into HeaderLoggedOut.js but it doesn't make sense. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll create the structure later.

Comment: Problem solved, I had to change somehow the Axios default base url in the main file. Thanks for support.